# PHP to Parse a HTML page and output a certain div

Tags: php, html, parsing

So I've been trying to embed a part of a website within my website due to security reasons I cannot disclose the website that I am trying to embed so for the purpose of this example I am going to use bbc.co.uk.

The following is the php/html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.bbc.co.uk/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($page);
$divs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($divs as $div) {
    // Loop through the DIVs looking for one withan id of "content"
    // Then echo out its contents (pardon the pun)
    if ($div->getAttribute('id') === 'orb-footer') {
         echo $div->nodeValue;
    }
}
?>  
</body>

<footer>

</footer>
</html>
```

However when I load the page I get left with a page displaying the php code. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please.

Thank you!!

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Hi that's weird I just get left with a blank page. Using PHP version 5.5.9.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail correction: I get left with a page displaying the php code.

Comment: You can check the link https://flinkhub.com/pgflink/testing.php , mine PHP version is 5.6.29,

Comment: 'I get left with a page displaying the php code', this means your server is not rendering PHP code.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail ah nice, it's working for you. No idea why it won't work for me and there are no errors in any of the logs that I can see.

Comment: restart your php service and which web server are you using?

Comment: I am using an apache web server.

Comment: Try to run any other php file, and i hope you hv configured your apache web server properly to handle php request

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail just tried a simple PHP script that echos Hello World! and it works!

Comment: Put php code at top of the page.

Comment: @MohdAsimSuhail that does not work either!

Comment: Does the file end in .php? If you try and run an html webpage with php, it won't work.

Comment: Ah, thats my mistake. Thanks! :) Silly me!

Answer (score 2):

***This is a general guide for solving PHP issues like this, and it's in no way a direct or specific "drop-in" solution for this answer***

**Check the loaded source on your browser after loading the page**

If the page on the browser that you are loading is blank, try viewing the source using **Ctrl+U** on Chrome, or just right clicking anywhere on the page and choosing the option to view source.

Is the source empty? Then that must mean that the error is from PHP/server.

Is the source fully/partially loaded? That means the error must lie in the PHP code you wrote. Try doing `$doc->loadHtml( htmlentities($page) )` instead.

**Use a PHP debugger such as XDebug**

Nowadays it's easy to use a PHP debugger seeing that it can easily be integrated with most PHP IDEs. Try stepping through the code line-by-line and check where the problem lies in.

Comment: Thanks for this, will give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Using `$doc->loadHtml( htmlentities($page) )` did not work.

Comment: The php code cannot have an error as @MohdAsimSuhai tried it and it worked for him. Has to be a problem with the server.

Comment: How are you running the PHP server? XAMPP/LAMP/WAMP or other packages? Directly from the php CLI?

Comment: I will have to ask my administrator for that information as I did not set up this server.

Comment: @BEE did you try writing and loading a raw HTML page through the server to be sure that it is functioning correctly?

Comment: Yes I did, I even tried a basic PHP script that echo's Hello, World! and that worked. So the server is rendering the PHP code.